# Groovy and spring under same transaction

Tags: spring, groovy, transactions

I'm struggling with legacy code. I'm creating unit tests so I've decided to use groovy to fill database with required legacy data. Normally in my code I using ibatis for persistence. I'd like to rollback test in the end. Problem is that when I create row via groovy then I use it's id to create row via ibatis I get constraint violation exception - parent key not found.

When I use groovy to persist parent and than create child based on parents id it works perfectly fine.

Also I can't use @Transactional because of problems with XML parser (legacy code FTW :/ )

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = [ "../dao/impl/ibatis/spring-data-context-config.xml",  "classpath:/pl/com/betacom/treq/dao-context.xml"])
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class FinancingForIltCreationTest {

@Autowired
IFinancingForIltDAO financingForIltDAO;

@Autowired
Sql sql;

@Autowired
DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;

private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    transactionStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    transactionManager.rollback(transactionStatus);
    transactionStatus = null;
}

@Test
public void shallCreateFinancingForIlt() throws Exception {
    //given
    IltOffering offering = new IltOffering("GOING_DOWN_TO_UBERGROUND", offeringTempId, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2011-07-21"), java.sql.Date.valueOf("2012-07-21"));
    offering.insert(sql); // it's inserted by groovy
    //when
    FinancingForIltDTO financingForIltDTO = createFinancingForIlt(offering.id).build(financingForIltDAO); // it's my assembler inserting via iBatis
    //then
    assertNotNull(financingForIltDTO.id);
}
```

Configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="dataSourceIn"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>####</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>####</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>####</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>####</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSourceIn" />
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="sql" class="groovy.sql.Sql">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it was a database schema issue.